Integrate esewa in ios , Swift version 5.10
When I tried to integrate eSewa in SwiftUI.
I faced error --> EsewaSDK/UIFont+Extenstion.swift:39: Fatal error: Please check that the font is properly added to the app.
How can I solve this.
I have followed this documentation from esewa -> https://developer.esewa.com.np/pages/iOS#credentials&urls
They have not mention anything about the fonts.
I have created custom viewcontroller to represent in swiftUI using UIViewControllerRepresentable

In swiftui solved using
ContentView()
.onAppear(perform: {
UIFont.loadFonts()
})
